# stop start music - Libgdx Java

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my game I have a music class that organizes and plays all of the music:

```
public class MusicPlayer extends Game{
(..)
    public static void MainBackgroundMusic(){

    if(backgroundMusicPlaying != true){
        backgroundMusic.play();
        backgroundMusic.setVolume(0.1f);
        backgroundMusic.setLooping(true);
        backgroundMusicPlaying = true;
        }

    }

    public static void BackgroundStop(){
    if(backgroundMusicPlaying = true){
        backgroundMusic.stop();
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to stop the music from playing, during levels then restart it again. But when i try and restart it it doesn't play again.

I call the music to play at the start of the game:

```
public OptionScreen(final Game1 gam){
    (..)
    MusicPlayer.MainBackgroundMusic();
    (..)
    }
    public void render(float delta) {
       (..)
}
```

Then during the start of the level I call the stop:

```
public InsaneLevels(Game1 gam) {
        (..)
        MusicPlayer.BackgroundStop();
        (..)
    }
    public void render(float delta) {
        (..)
}
```

And when i go back to the start it doesn't replay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the backgroundMusicPlaying to false inside of your stop method. Guess you forgot this.
Also you should have this:

`backgroundMusicPlaying == true`

Instead of:

`backgroundMusicPlaying = true`

```
    public static void BackgroundStop() {
        if (backgroundMusicPlaying == true) {
            backgroundMusic.stop();
            backgroundMusicPlaying = false;
        }
    }
```